# Can XeLaTeX | LuaTeX import movies?

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, media9, movie15

It seems that XeLaTeX cannot handle movies. I imported movies into PDF produced with pdflatex compiler using the multimedia package that comes with beamer. My search over various  boards revealed that currently there is no package that could import movies under XeLaTeX. Is that correct? And what about LuaLaTeX?

**UPDATE:** This question became obsolete with the advent of [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media9) package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a version of `movie15.sty` called `movie15_dvipdfmx.sty`, see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/asymptote/patches/, that allows the inclusion of movies with xelatex with `\includemovie`.

Since it may not be clear, as there is no documentation, the package `movie15_dvipdfmx.sty` should be passed the option `dvipdfmx` for use with xelatex, that is, `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{movie15_dvipdfmx}`.

Comment: No, it does not work.
 
    `\documentclass[unicode]{article}`
    `\usepackage{graphicx}`
    `\usepackage{hyperref}`
    `\usepackage{movie15_dvipdfmx}`
    `\begin{document}`
    `\begin{figure}\centering`
    `\includemovie[label=movie-04-03`
    `,text={\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2010-04-03.png}`
    `]{}{}{Video/2010-04-03-xvid.avi}`
    `\caption{\movieref[pause]{movie-04-03}{Run}}`
    `\label{fig:04-03}`
    `\end{figure}`
    `\end{document}`

produces no output with xelatex. It terminates with the error

`! Undefined control sequence.`
`<argument> \pdfmark`

Comment: @Igor `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{movie15_dvipdfmx}` works for me.

Comment: A very odd requirement that a package designed to work with `dvipdfmx` should require it as an option!

Comment: @Alan: `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{movie15_dvipdfmx}` with `xelatex` has limited functionality as compared to  `pdflatex`. Bottom produced with  `\movieref[pause]{movie-04-03}{\RunVideo}`   wehre   `\RunVideo`   puts a pictures seemed to be not operational.

Comment: @Alan: the recommendation is that you rename or symlink that package to movie15.sty and put it upstream in your input path.  Then you call it with `\usepackage{dvipdfmx}[movie15]` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Lualatex works perfectly with multimedia package.