# XeTeX + movie15_dvipdfmx -- Use of `\pdfmdfivesum` doesn't match its definition

Tags: xetex, movie15

I'm trying to embed movies in my document.  That would normally mean use the `movie15` package but since I'm also using the xetex engine I have to use `movie15_dvipdfmx`. (See “ [Can XeLaTeX | LuaTeX import movies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/can-xelatex-luatex-import-movies) ”)

Here's a sample file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{movie15_dvipdfmx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Whispering-gallery mode in a quarter circle:
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[
  poster,
  text={\small(Loading Circle-m-increase3.mp4)}
]{6cm}{6cm}{Circle-m-increase3.mp4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

See [“Generating PDF Animations with LaTeX”](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PDFmovie.html) for the tutorial and [movie file](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/movieExample/Circle-m-increase3.mp4).

Compiling this gives me these errors:

> ```
> ! Use of \pdfmdfivesum doesn't match its definition.
> \pdf@filemdfivesum {->\pdfmdfivesum file{
>
> l.4 \begin{document}
>
> ? s
> OK, entering \scrollmode...
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> \ReFiCh@Check ...#1\edef #2{\ReFiCh@CheckSum {#3}}
>                                                   \ifx #2\ReFiCh@Separator #...
> l.4 \begin{document}
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
> [1] (./movie_xetex.aux)
> ! Use of \pdfmdfivesum doesn't match its definition.
> \pdf@filemdfivesum {->\pdfmdfivesum file{
>
> l.12 \end{document}
>
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> \ReFiCh@Check ...#1\edef #2{\ReFiCh@CheckSum {#3}}
>                                                   \ifx #2\ReFiCh@Separator #...
> l.12 \end{document}
>
>  )
> (see the transcript file for additional information)
> Output written on movie_xetex.pdf (1 page).
> Transcript written on movie_xetex.log.
> ```

Just those four errors, two at `\begin{document}` and two at `\end{document}`.  Thing is, if you open the pdf in a suitably capable reader (like Acrobat Pro or Reader), the animation does work.

I googled the error message but I didn't get anything useful.  Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`movie15_dvipdfmx` defines for xetex  a dummy `\pdfmdfivesum` such that it needs the `file` keyword (in pdftex `file` is optional).  `rerunfilecheck.sty` loaded by hyperref now tries to use `\pdfmdfivesum` without the `file` keyword and fails. You can load `rerunfilecheck` before `movie15_dvipdfmx` to avoid the error, but it would be much better if `movie15_dvipdfmx` would find a saner solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the package defines `\pdfmdfivesum`, a primitive which is provided by `pdftex`, by itself if it not defined yet. The used definition is `\def\pdfmdfivesum file #1{#1}`, but the `file` is actually marked optional in the `pdftex` manual! On solution would be to not redefine and use `\pdfmdfivesum` but use a replacement macro for it, e.g:

replace this code in the `movie15_dvipdfmx` package:

```
 \ifx\@undefined\pdfmdfivesum
  \def\pdfmdfivesum file #1{#1}
 \fi
```

with:

```
 \ifx\@undefined\pdfmdfivesum
  \def\@pdfmdfivesum file #1{#1}
\else
  \let\@pdfmdfivesum\pdfmdfivesum
 \fi
```

and replace all usages of `\pdfmdfivesum file` with `\@pdfmdfivesum file`.

I still get then an error:

```
** WARNING ** Could not open file: Circle-m-increase3.mp4
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command fstream (pdf:) failed.
...
```

but I think that is a different thing. I downloaded the MP4 file.