# Considerations when migrating from XeTeX to LuaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex

What are the things to know when moving from XeTeX to LuaTeX, particularly when it comes to TTF/OTF support and OpenType features?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only difference is for Linux: OpenType or TrueType fonts from the TeX directory structure, e.g. the texgyre fonts, have to be assigned by its filename for `XeTeX`, e.g. `\fontspec{texgyre-pagella.otf}`. LuaTeX itself also searches the TeX font directories, the reason why LuaTeX finds such font defined by its family name, e.g. `\fontspec{TexGyre-Pagella}`. For MiKTeX it should make no difference, fonts should be found.

The package `mathspec` works only for `XeTeX`. And `polyglossia` doesn't work with LuaLaTeX yet.

Comment: In XeTeX on Linux, I currently use the font name, not the font filename. For example, I do `\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}` and it works. Does `fontspec` work with LuaLaTeX? I get an error when I run `lualatex` on a tex file using `fontspec` (using TL2009)...

Comment: Are you sure that font names don't work on TeXLive? The font database is generated by lualatex/luaotfload/mkluatexfontsdb and if a font is found at all why shouldn't the font name be in the database too? There is certainly no problem on miktex, lualatex accepts even a lot of name variants like `\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagella}`.

Comment: @Ulrike: I wrote, that `XeTeX` needs the file name!

Comment: Ah. Sorry I read it the other way round. Doesn't this here solve the problem: http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-350003.4.4? (But it can also lead to trouble if too much folders are searched and used by xetex. XeTeX doesn't like it very much if a font exists in two variants.)

Comment: I know that, but I do not like such hacks

Comment: @Herbert: I'd not call it a hack, it is the standard way to configure fontconfig (which is used by XeTeX) to look for fonts in non-default directories (even the defaults are read from similar configuration file(s).)

Comment: @Khaled: XeTeX is based on TeX, the reason why it should search _by default_ the TeX directory for fonts. This should not be done by a user configuration.

Comment: @Herbert: The problem is that the barrier between the "TeX-fonts" used by TeX engines (and stored in TeX directories) and on the other side the system fonts used by other applications has fallen and that it is no longer really clear where such fonts should be stored at best and who should manage (eg update) them. It is a problem if e.g. a libertine otf is in the system folder, a ttf and another otf version in the texmf tree - and if on top of this a pfb exists too. I think in the long run miktex and texlive should install fonts in the system folders.

Comment: @Ulrike, sure that's the problem but LuaTeX solved it in user friendly way, XeTeX not ... and of course, all fonts should go into one system and one local folder.

Comment: It is not luatex which solves it, it is luaotfload which generates the database with the help of variables like OSFONTSDIR - and it is imho (apart from the blacklist) not really possible to configure the pathes. Xetex uses fontconfig which *has* configurations files, and miktex as default *does* configure fontconfig/xetex so that it searches the texmf. This is on windows easy as there is no system fontconfig so miktex uses its own variant. I don't no why TeXLive doesn't do it perhaps it can't be done on linux (and so linux should be blamed ;-)).

Comment: @Ulrike: if you are on unix and OSFONTSDIR is not set, luaotfload will attempt to read fontconfig's configuration files, so that is a way to have a bit more control on system search paths.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to move from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX, you should read [lualatex-doc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lualatex-doc). If you want to use from ConTeX MkII to MkIV, many things will change.

Comment: I'm interested in moving to a modern cutting-edge system, and mostly benefiting from font expansion while still keep an easy way to manage TTF/OTF fonts with OpenType features. I do not plan on using ConTeXt though, but rather keep with LaTeX for now (I'm using specific LaTeX packages such as `bibleref`).

Answer (score 5):

There are some caveats with multilingual typesetting with OpenType shaping features; I'm not really the one to ask about it, though. XeTeX uses the ICU to do its OpenType magic, which as I understand things is a lot more comprehensive than what's currently done by LuaTeX and its supporting machinery. For example, unless things have changed recently, I don't believe that LuaTeX will be able to typeset Indic languages correctly.

XeTeX isn't a silver bullet here either, but I think its coverage is more comprehensive.

Comment: Most of my needs as far as OpenType features are concerned are ligatures, letter/word spacing, oldstyle/uppercase numbers, small caps, alternate forms. Nothing really fancy.

Comment: In that case no problem :)

Answer (score 5):

As I actually ended up switching from XeTeX to LuaTeX, I've met a few other problems.

Most notably:

- LetterSpace and WordSpace options in `fontspec` are not supported in LuaTeX, so you have to use `textls` from microtype like in PDFTeX in order to achieve tracking;
- `textls` sometimes break with small caps (see [textls breaks smallcaps with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26141/textls-breaks-smallcaps-with-luatex)).

Answer (score 0):

My main motivation for moving from XeTeX to LuaTeX was movies. As it is said in my posts ([Can XeLaTeX | LuaTeX import movies ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/can-xelatex-luatex-import-movies), [Why \movieref does not work under XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28345/why-movieref-does-not-work-under-xelatex))  XeTeX has troubles with importing movies. The latter one is still unresolved.

Comment: `movie15` has been deprecated in favor of package [`media9`](http://ctan.org/pkg/media9), which does work under XeTeX.