# textls breaks smallcaps with luatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, small-caps, libertine

I'm switching a code to LuaTex from XeTeX. In XeTeX, I had a combination of tracking and small caps using `LetterSpace` and `WordSpace` parameters in `fontspec` calls, but these are not supported in with LuaTeX.

When using `textls` with `lualatex` from TL2011 and `microtype v2.5 <beta-06>`, small caps are broken. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}                                                         

\usepackage{fontspec}                                                           
\usepackage{xunicode}                                                           
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}                                             
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}                                                 
\newfontfamily\scfont[Letters=SmallCaps]{Linux Libertine O}                     

\usepackage{microtype}                                                          

\begin{document}            

\scshape{Example of small caps}                                                 

\textls{\scshape{Example of small caps with textls}}                            

\scshape{\textls{Example of small caps with textls inside}}                     

{\lsstyle\scshape{Example of small caps with lsstyle}}                          

{\scfont Example of Letters=SmallCaps}                                          

{\scfont\textls{Example of textls with Letters=SmallCaps}}                      

\end{document}
```

and the result I get:

[image: examples of sc with textls in luatex]

Is there a way to get small caps with tracking in LuaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to activate the SmallCaps feature with `fontspec`

```
\usepackage{fontspec} 
 \usepackage{xunicode}    
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
 \setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine C},         
             SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
 \newfontfamily\scfont[Letters=SmallCaps]{Linux Libertine O}
```

[image]

the name of the font maybe different in your installation:

```
["familyname"]="Linux Libertine C",
   ["filename"]={ "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/LinLibertine_C-4.0.4.ttf", false },
   ["fontname"]="LinLibertineC",
   ["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Capitals",
    ["family"]="Linux Libertine C",
    ["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Capitals",
    ["psname"]="LinLibertineC",
```

The font is available for download here: http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/

Comment: Linux Libertine C cannot be found: `! Font \EU2/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/sc/10.95=name:LinuxLibertineC:mode=node;script
=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+smcp; at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not
 found or bad.`

Comment: see my edit. Maybe your names are different

Comment: Ok, I had to use the psname for the OTF font, so `LinLibertineCapitalsO`. Thank you very much. How come this has to be done?

Comment: @Herbert : two questions: 1. I cannot find a Linux Libertine C anywhere on the internet. Where can I get it? I downloaded the most recent otf and ttf files (version 5.3.0), but there was no SmallCaps font in it. 2. So, I had to try your approach with other fonts, without success. Does your approach still work?

Comment: see http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/

Comment: @Herbert : thanks for that. But still, I don't get your solution to run.

Comment: @Herbert : Is your approach supposed to work only with that font?

Comment: yes, the author changes the fonts ...

Comment: I found a solution that works here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105627/12277