# LuaLaTeX, fontspec and tracking with microtype

Tags: fontspec, luatex, microtype, opentype

I try to get microtype's tracking working but without success: up-to-date TeXlive 2011 (lualatex 0.70.1) with microtype v2.5 beta 07. Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[tracking,letterspace=500]{microtype}
\begin{document}\parindent0em

\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\textsc{stealing sheep}

\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\textsc{stealing sheep}
\end{document}
```

Latin Modern works fine (letterspaced small caps) but not Libertine (letterspaced lowercase letters). The only difference between both fonts is that Latin Modern has small caps in a separate file. Any ideas how I could get the same working for Libertine? The following does not work, however:

```
\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Nor does:

```
\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Edit: the following does work (with side effects, see below):

```
\fontspec[Renderer=Basic]{Linux Libertine O}
```

2nd edit: See related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/fontspec-lua-microtype-renderer-basic-no-longer-working-for-specific-font-styl).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1YZff.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [textls breaks smallcaps with luatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26141/textls-breaks-smallcaps-with-luatex)

Comment: I have seen the post but the answer it related to the truetype version of Libertine. I would like to use opentype fonts (see also my comment to Herbert's answer).

Comment: My question related to the OTF version of Linux Libertine. Afaik, TrueType and OTF fonts are dealt the same way with XeTeX and LuaTeX. Furthermore, `ttf` files can actually have OpenType features.

Comment: The solution proposed is to assign 'SmallCapsFont' with 'fooC' where 'fooC' is an opentype font with small caps instead of lowercase characters (see my remarks below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a bug (or, if one were more polite: incompatibility) in luatex. I've just reported it [on the luatex list](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2011-September/004343.html).

Edit: ... and I got an answer, persuading me to be more polite, indeed - it's not a bug but microtype's using a legacy command.

The simple solution is: load the fonts with `Renderer=Basic` (side effects are yet to be discovered).

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I hope they can find the time to fix it.

Comment: I found two side effects of `Renderer=Basic` sofar: TeX ligatures and letterspaced small caps italics do not work.

Comment: To note a further side effect, spacing of numbers is incorrect. It looks like proportional numbers revert to monospaced.

Comment: I can extent the proportional number side effect. If I don't specify `Renderer=Basic` the body of my text is all good with `Numbers={Oldstyle, Proportional}` but inside any `\textls` and `\lsstyle` commands numbers change to proportional lining numbers. If I *do* specify `Renderer=Basic` then all numbers in the document are set lining and proportional. If I remove the `Proportional` option when loading my typeface then everything works but all numbers are typeset monospaced.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineCapitalsO},
          SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[tracking,letterspace=500]{microtype}
\begin{document}\parindent0em

stealing sheap

\textsc{Stealing Sheep}

\textls[800]{\scshape Stealing Sheep}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Herbert. However, I do not have a font 'LinLibertineCapitalsO' (separate fonts with small caps) but rather 'Linux Libertine O' including small caps (opentype 'smcp' feature, font stored in texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/fxlr.otf). I think, I have got a regular TeXlive2011 distribution.

Comment: While reading Raphink's comment above: Just to confirm that I would like the tracking function working with opentype fonts.

Comment: then use the name `Linux Libertine C`. I do not use the open type fonts from TeXLive, I have the ones from sourceforge installed

Comment: Sourceforge does provide a font 'LinLibertineCapitalsO'. Still, this is not what I am looking for. I would like to use the small caps feature of an opentype font. I used Libertine in the sample code as it is a public font for anybody to test. But in my 'real-life' text I would like to use GaramondPremierPro, for example. It does not provide a separate small caps font file but rather the smcp feature.

Comment: what do you think what kind of font I used?? It is the OpenType one ...

Comment: Sorry but it seems that I'm not able to make myself understood. Your solution is to use a separate font file (by 'SmallCapsFont=LinLibertineCapitalsO'). In this font, the lowercase characters are replaced by their small caps representation. My question is: how to use an opentype font with regular lowercase characters *and* additional small caps characters (accessed by feature 'smcp'). Thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: see my editet answer

Comment: Hm, the edited answer shows the difference between 500/1000em tracking and 800/1000em letterspacing for 'LinLibertineCapitalsO'. It works if you have got a separate small caps font file. How would it work with, for example, Tex Gyre Heros? Heros does not have a separate small caps file. (Thanks again)

Comment: `\fontspec[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{TeXgyre Heros}`

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. It does not work for me, as written in my original question. The output contains letterspaced non-smallcaps characters. (If \fontspec is in the praemble, I only get the LatinModern font). Thanks for trying.