# Junicode and Small Caps

Tags: luatex, small-caps

How can I use Junicode small caps fonts with LuaLaTeX? 
The solution posted in 
[textls breaks smallcaps with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26141/textls-breaks-smallcaps-with-luatex)
did not work or I just can't fix it.

Example:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Junicode},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Jun‌​icode}
\newfontfamily\scfont[Letters=SmallCaps]{Junicode}
```

Comment: We could do with a bit more than 'did not work' Could you post an example of what you did, and an image or description of the result.

Comment: @Erasm It's best to edit your question than adding code as a comment.

Answer (score 7):

What is wrong with the simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
The quick brown {\scshape smallcaps} jumps over the \emph{italic} fox.
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: It does not work with microtype's tracking: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/lualatex-fontspec-and-tracking-with-microtype

Comment: @Erasm I think that microtype tracking does not work correctly with LuaTeX anyway.

Comment: @Erasm: If you use version 2.5 of the `microtype` package -- still in (late) beta and available from http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423 -- you can use the following options when used with luatex >=0.62: "Protrusion", "Expansion, "Auto" (the combination of "protrusion" and "expansion"), and "Tracking"; what's still left out are "Spacing" and "Kerning". That said, it does indeed seem to be the case that "Tracking" doesn't work correctly with the smallcaps font of Junicode (it sets it in "normal" lowercase letters).