# Letterspacing/font expansion in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, letterspacing

I am a few months into learning LaTeX. I would like to use `microtype` with LuaLaTeX and I would like to obtain letter spacing for my smallcaps. I've tried to follow some of the threads on the subject but when I try to implement the suggestions I just end up with errors. The minimal example below works as far as protrusion/expansion, but the letterspacing is just ignored. Please excuse my frankenCode... I cobbled it together from a bunch of different threads on this forum... any advice would be much appreciated. I *need* the font expansion due to very narrow columns and I need to use LuaLaTeX due to some packages I'm working with.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}

\directlua{fonts.expansions.setups.default.stretch=5.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Numbers=OldStyle]{Arno Pro}

\usepackage{microtype}

\newfontfamily{\regBlackSmallCaps}%
[Letters={SmallCaps},
LetterSpace=3.0, Scale=.95]
{ArnoPro-regular}

\begin{document}

{\regBlackSmallCaps This is a test}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Thank you Mico for responding.
After going though the answers to similar posts I've managed to get a little further. Using `Renderer=Basic` and making sure I have updated versions of `fontspec` and `microtype`, the code below works. The first line spaces correctly, the second line doesn't. I'm wondering if there is a way to Incorporate the `\textls{\addfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}` into the newfontfamily specifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}

\setmainfont[
]{Arno Pro}

\newfontfamily{\smBlackSC} %Small | Black | Smallcap
[Letters={UppercaseSmallCaps, SmallCaps},
LetterSpace=9 .0, 
Scale=.9,
Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
{ArnoPro-regular}

\begin{document}

{\smBlackSC{\textls{\addfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}Lorem Ipsum}}}

{\smBlackSC Lorem Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The user guide to the latest version (2.5) of the `microtype` package notes, on pp. 26f., that the command  `\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}` "should *not* be used with this package, as it will basically override the settings made by microtype -- despite the naming, the above lines have nothing to do with the this package." [emphasis in the original] Incidentally, if all you want or need is letterspacing capability, you may want to look into using the `letterspace` package.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Did you not try out to add `Renderer=Basic` to `\newfontfamily`? Something like `[Renderer=Basic,Letters=…,Letterspace=…`. What happens then?

Comment: Thanks Speravir. I tried that and it doesn't work for me... no errors but no letterspacing either.

Comment: I ended up putting `\textls{\addfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}` wherever I use small caps which was messy but works. another problem is that Renderer=Basic breaks my use of xcolor that I set up in my \newfontfamilies so I have to declare the color again whenever I use smallcaps and my second color. Frustrating. So, I'm hoping there will be further development of LuaLaTeX, Microtype and fontspec so they will play better together.

Comment: I just tried the example using `TeX Gyre Pagella`, because the `Arno` font is not available (to me). `Microtype` was updated 2013/05/23 and I used the the beta7 before that. In both cases you can use letterspacing with LuaLaTeX. The 2nd example works for me on an updated  _TeXLive 2013_.

Comment: @theobear what is the status of this question? Are you still seeking a solution?

Comment: @Paul, Andy's comment is correct the updated version of Microtype solved the problem.

Comment: Great to hear; would you or @Andy like to write an answer?

Comment: Would someone post an answer please?

Comment: @Andy, feel free to answer. I'll do so in the next couple of days if I don't see that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My previous comment seems to solve the question and is posted here now as an answer:*

I just tried the example using TeX Gyre Pagella, because the Arno font is not available (to me). Microtype was updated 2013/05/23 and I used the the beta7 before that. In both cases you can use letterspacing with LuaLaTeX. The 2nd example works for me on an updated TeXLive 2013.