# Command names with utf-8/special characters

Tags: macros, unicode

Is it possible to define

```
\newcommand{\√}[1]{\sqrt{#1}}
```

as commands like this one would sometimes be easier to use.

Comment: Which engine do you use? This is awkward in pdfTeX, but easy enough with a UTF-8 engine.

Comment: i guess you mean something like luatex with a utf-8 engine, i'm using pdflatex.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If there were no argument to the macro, this would be just a matter of loading the [`newunicodechar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) package or using the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` macro. For the "character" to accept arguments, a slightly different approach is needed.

If you use XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use either of

```
\catcode`\√=\active
\newcommand{√}[1]{\sqrt{#1}}
…
$√{2}$
```

or

```
\newcommand{\√}[1]{\sqrt{#1}}
…
$\√{2}$
```

(The second approach is more robust.)

With pdfTeX the `\√` syntax will not work because of the way pdfTeX handles input (it is theoretically possible to achieve this, though). This leaves the only way (taken and modified from `newunicodechar` documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\expandafter\newcommand\csname u8:\detokenize{√}\endcsname[1]{%
  \sqrt{#1}}

\begin{document}

$√{2}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks - curiously with luatex characters like '⟨','⟩' don't work well but otherwise - it is great. Definitely something i should have a look at. till now i've worked with pdflatex

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: `\newunicodechar{⟨}{\langle} \newunicodechar{⟩}{\rangle}` works for me in LuaTeX and TeX Live 2011.

Comment: ah thanks - most definitely should look at LuaTeX - should i watch something when migrating from pdfTeX, are there any complications/breaking points - looking through 20 pages for errors would be gruesome.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: See these questions: [one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex) [two](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex) [three](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/considerations-when-migrating-from-xetex-to-luatex)

Comment: the move to LuaLaTeX was the best thing  TeXrelated I did in the last few months - thanks again.