# Micro symbol µ in lstlisting

Tags: symbols, listings

I'm writing a report about a website I'm working on to play cards online. I use lstlisting to display my PHP, JavaScript and HTML code. The problem is that I'm using a lot of µ's in my JavaScript codes. For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=some code]
  µ.a('error', µ.m('Server responded: ' + r));
\end{lstlisting}
```

I use the micro symbol because i wanted to have a shortcut for certain functions.

Now, the problem is that LaTeX won't compile these µ's. As output I get to see .a('error', .m('Server responded: ' + r)); LaTeX simply seems to ignore those µ's. I tried to fix this by using:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

but this leads to an error: Package utf8x Error: Character181appearedalone.

Any toughts on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is xelatex/lualatex + fontspec an option? If so, all problems should just go away (no inputenc required)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm relatively new to LaTeX. Are these things just packages or ... ?

EDIT: I'm using MikTeX, and doesn't that have XeTeX included?

Comment: It is possible, I had the same problem displaying \alpha and \beta. I hope I still have the source of this old report, just a sec... Edit: found it, you can use `\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\#]` and then `#$\alpha$#` or `#$\mu$#` in your case.

Comment: But then I'd have to change all my appearances of µ in my code, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(pdf)latex solution:

If you use the symbol `µ` only inside `lstlisting` you can use the option `literate`.

Here an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=some code,literate={µ}{$\upmu$}1]
  µ.a('error', µ.m('Server responded: ' + r));
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this actually does the trick! I already tried something with literate, but that didn't work, but your code does. :)
Of course it would be handier to just use µ everywhere in my document, and not only inside lstlisting, but that can be easily fixed with \textmu I assume.

Comment: @Sebastian: You can also use it inside the document body. Therefor you should have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28031/command-names-with-utf-8-special-characters

Comment: For anyone in future that wants to use literate but it may not work: check if you have the correct sign at all places and copy&paste them. I tried the example in the question for myself (did not copy Marco’s answer but wrote the literate myself) and could not get it to work until I copied the whole answer. There is `'MICRO SIGN' (U+00B5)` (the one that is used in the question and answer) and then there is `'GREEK SMALL LETTER MU' (U+03BC)` that my keyboard layout g