# Automatic kerning

Tags: kerning

With the font I am using, the f touches a following closing quotation mark. I am præventing that from happening by periodically replacing all instances of `f'` with `f\,'`. Is there a better way to do this? I am already using XeTeX character classes for automatic language switching.

Comment: One could **over limited domains of text** make `f` active to behave automatically in the way desired.  But active `f` would break any macro invocation containing an `f` and possibly other things, too.  If this idea is appealing, I would create `\kernfON` and `\kernfOFF` to make `f` active and normal, respectively.  Then you could turn it on before a text block, and turn it off afterwards.  If you want to see an answer to this effect, please let me know.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes,
I think having to do this all the time would be more cumbersome than automatic replacements, which could also be done with a script together with compilation (or built into a saving command in vim).

Comment: Are you using an OpenType font? Then you could take care of this in a feature file.

Comment: Forget my comment -- you say you are using XeTeX, which does not have feature files. Is it an option for you to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @MarkvanAtten,
I don’t know anything about LuaLaTeX, and at the moment I don’t have time for big rearrangements. Anyway, this is not a huge problem, just wanted to see if anyone had a more elegant solution than mine. (I suppose I could always modify the otf with Fontforge.)

Comment: The rearrangement is not necessarily big. Some things to consider are discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/considerations-when-migrating-from-xetex-to-luatex?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290642/10995) you could use the XeTeX interchar classes to add custom kerning between `f` and `'`.  I didn't find a font where `f` and `'` touch, but the spacing between `f` and `'` is fairly tight in Adobe Garamond Pro, and for a word ending in `ff` they do touch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclassf
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclassprime
\XeTeXcharclass`\f\charclassf
\XeTeXcharclass`\'\charclassprime
\XeTeXinterchartoks\charclassf\charclassprime={\kern.15em}
\begin{document}
`bluff' `surf'

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
`bluff' `surf'
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Remark for people using Garamond:  While looking for a font where the `f` touches the `'` (and while previously search for a font where `f` and `b` touch) I found that [EB Garamond](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/ebgaramond/Specimen.pdf) has ligatures for all these combinations, which are a pain to kern by hand in other fonts.  EB Garamond is great!