# XeLaTeX: discretionary ligatures with discretion

Tags: ligatures

Say I have turned on 'discretionary' ligatures with `\fontspec[Ligatures=Rare]{Junicode}` but want to disable the st and the ct ligatures; is that possilbe?

Comment: In `luatex`, yes, with `selnolig` or by writing your own feature file. With `xetex`, I don’t know of a way, which doesn’t mean that none exists.

Comment: @Thérèse One could use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to insert `\kern0pt` bewteen the pairs `s`/`t` and `c`/`t` to prevent the ligature.

Comment: @HenriMenke, wouldn't this disturb st and ct in command names?

Comment: @Lawrence No. Charclasses aren't applied on tokenization, but on typesetting.

Comment: @HenriMenke, ah, I was thinking of active characters. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TeX ligatures can be broken up by inserting an explicit kern between the letters.  For instance, to prevent the `st` ligature, we might write `s\kern0pt t` instead.  This is tedious though, but fortunately `xetex` offers the concept of charclasses, which comes with the possibility of inserting custom tokens between characters, previously assigned to a class.

We proceed to define two classes, one for `c` and `s` and one for `t`:

```
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclasscs
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclasst
```

Then we assign the characters to these classes

```
\XeTeXcharclass`\c\charclasscs
\XeTeXcharclass`\s\charclasscs
\XeTeXcharclass`\t\charclasst
```

If in a character combination the left character is of class `\charclasscs` and the right of `\charclasst`, then we want to insert the kern `\kern0pt`

```
\XeTeXinterchartoks\charclasscs\charclasst={\kern0pt}
```

Finally we enable the functionality with

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % or 0 to disable
```

A complete example would read

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{Junicode.ttf}
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclasscs
\newXeTeXintercharclass\charclasst
\XeTeXcharclass`\c\charclasscs
\XeTeXcharclass`\s\charclasscs
\XeTeXcharclass`\t\charclasst
\XeTeXinterchartoks\charclasscs\charclasst={\kern0pt}
\begin{document}
st ct
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
st ct
\end{document}
```

> [image]

To restore hyphenation you'd have to use something more complicated

```
\XeTeXinterchartoks\charclasscs\charclasst={%
  \penalty10000\discretionary{-}{}{\kern0pt}%
  \penalty10000\hskip0pt\relax}
```

---

For completeness, here a solution using `luatex` and the [`selnolig`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/selnolig/selnolig.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec,selnolig}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{Junicode.ttf}
\nolig{ct}{c|t}
\nolig{st}{s|t}
\begin{document}
st ct
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a serious side-effect to this, it breaks hyphenation, causing un-der-stand-ing to be broken un-derstanding.

Comment: @Lawrence See the comment below the picture in my updated answer.

Comment: @Lawrence The hyphenation will be awkward, though, because `un-der-stand-ing` will be hyphenated `un-ders-tand-ing`.  Better use the LuaTeX solution.  Mico's package `selnolig` is really good.

Comment: Trying to switch to luatex …