# Playing sounds with Beamer+XeTeX+Linux without Acrobat

Tags: beamer, xetex, media9, multimedia, audio

AFAIK the natural choice for playing sounds in beamer is the `multimedia` package

But the [beamer documentation](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) says it only works with pdflatex:

> ∙ The sound objects do not work together with dvips and ps2pdf. They only work with pdflatex.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/can-xelatex-luatex-import-movies) is a similar question but for videos (I don't know if this changes things here). The author suggests moving to the `media9` package but it is designed to work with Adobe Acrobat and Flash Player and I don't want to use it

The answer of this question suggests using a package called `movie15_dvipdfmx` but a quick search in CTAN found [no results for it](http://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=movie15_dvipdfmx), which I find weird. I suppose this would require a manual installation of the package?

Are there any easier solutions?

Comment: Have you tried with LuaTeX instead of XeTeX (with no other changes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this is simply using `\href`

```
\begin{frame}
    \href{run:../relative/path/to/file.wav}{Example}
\end{frame}
```

There are no additional packages needed

The disadvantages of this approach are:

1. It will run your standard audio player which can open a big window in front of your slides
2. This does not work for some pdf visualizers such as [pdfpc](https://github.com/davvil/pdfpc/issues/76)

<sub>Marking this as correct until someone comes up with something better</sub>